# Cannot access to deployed apps in weblogic

Tags: deployment, weblogic

I have an angular app and I need to deploy it on a weblogic server that I'm running on a Docker container. the war is correctly installed on the server but when I try : localhost:port/context I can't access to the app.
[image]

Comment: What's the folder structure of your war file?  Also how have you configured your web.xml?  Did you specify a welcome-file-list?

Comment: this is my welcome-file-list `
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>`

Comment: An angular app is normally accessed using an index.html file (not jsp).  Where is your angular app contained within the war file?

Comment: Normally I'm deploying the same war on a Jboss server and it's working fine, when i Go to the context root, I see my login screen; I don't know if I should do more configurations on Weblogic. thanks for your help